# Problema con Pagina en PHP

Tags: php, html, css, msql

Tengo un problema con mi pagina de PHP porque cuando quiero ingresar un paciente o un Profesional o una sucursal, me lo ingresa en la base de datos pero no me los muestra en la pagina, como que aunque se agregaron no se muestran donde deverian, paso codigo de como muestro una sucursal:

```
<?php include 'model/conexion.php';
$consulta = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sucursal;");
$sucursal = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<body>
<?php include 'navbar.php' ?>
<div class="container bg-white mt-3">
    <div class="content row vh-10 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h1 class="text-center">Crear Nueva Sucursal</h1>
        <div class="col-auto">
        <form action="crear_sucursal.php" method="POST" autocomplete="false">

            
                <label class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" for="Nombre">Sucursal: 
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Sucursal" id="sucursal" placeholder="Escribe la nueva Sucursal" required>
                    <input class="btn btn-dark btn-md mb-3 mt-3 " style="margin-left: 15px;" type="submit" value="Agregar Sucursal" name="Agregar_sucursal">
                </label>
            
           
            
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container bg-white mt-3">
    <h2 class="text-center">Sucursales Existentes</h2>
    <div class="content">
        <table style="margin:auto; width:55%; margin-bottom: 5vw;"  class="table table-hover table-bordered bg-light text-black" >
            <thead>
                <th style="font-size: 23px;" >Nombre</th>

                <th style="margin:auto; width:12%; font-size: 23px;">Acciones</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    foreach($sucursal as $dato){
                ?>
                <tr style="background:white;">
                    
                    <td style="font-size: 20px;"><?php echo $dato->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL ?></td>
                    <td class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                   
                   <a href="eliminar_sucrusal.php?id=<?php echo $dato->ID_SUCURSAL ?>" class="btn btn-danger" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Como se deberian mostrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca creo la sucursal y la guardo en la BDD:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Agregar_sucursal'])){
include 'model/conexion.php';
$nombre=$_POST['Sucursal'];

$consulta = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO sucursal(NOMBRE_SUCURSAL) 
 VALUES(?);");    
$result = $consulta->execute([$nombre]);
if($result == true){
    header("Location: sucursal.php");
}else{
    echo "no se pudo agregar el contacto";
}
}



?>
```

Disuclpen pasar mucho codigo pero asi veran si tiene algun error, desde ya les agradezco mucho.

Comment: PD: El head lo saque porque no me dejaba agregar mucho codigo, cualquier duda o algo que necesiten estare por aca esperando su respuesta.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que "no se muestra como deberían"?, no dejas ninguna descripción,

Comment: Me refiero a que no me muestra ni su nombre ni sus caracteristicas, literalmente es como si no se agregara a la base de datos pero cuando me fijo en la bdd si esta ingresado, porque antes me funcionaba muy bien y todo pero cuando lo pase para un hosting distinto se romipo algo que no tengo idea, disculpa si no fui muy especifico.

Comment: Te arroja algún error? De ser así, agrégalo a la pregunta. También puedes revisar que te llega en `$sucursal` usando la función `var_dump($sucursal);`.

Comment: Me fije en la consola y no me tira ningun error,  lo unico que noto es que cuando le doy a boton de crear sucursal pasa a crear_sucursal.php y me envia NULL. Ahora bien hoy me fije en la pagina y las sucursales que cree ayes aparecieron hoy, no tengo ni idea porque.

Comment: *"Ahora bien hoy me fije en la pagina y las sucursales que cree ayes aparecieron hoy, no tengo ni idea porque."* -> Porque tienes la página cacheada, por eso no ves los cambios hasta que pasa un tiempo. Desactiva la caché de tu navegador para ver los cambios cuando trabajas.

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, tu lo que necesitas es fetch async y tu problema se resuelve. Si no sabes como usarlo me indicas y te preparo un ejemplo

Comment: Saque el cache del navegador, tambien el del hosting y utilize Ctrl + shift + R y no me mostro nada. @Benito-B

Comment: @Jefferson Jimenez claro todo puede servir. ahora bien no se utilizar fetch async

Comment: Quiero dejar bien en claro que mi pagina funcionaba bien cuando estaba goodady, pero como cambie de hosting a siteGround no me redirije a ninguna pagina, tampoco me agrega y tampoco no muestra los datos.

Comment: Otro dato que dejo, cuando creo una sucursal me envia a crar_sucursal.php y no me redirije a sucursal.php, pero cuando borro el cache dinamico del hosting y actualizo la pagina me aparece la sucursal creada. Como puedo solucionar eso? para que cuando ingreso vuelva a sucursal.php y me muestre la sucursal?.

Answer (score 1):

fijate que ya elimino el php

```html
<body>
<?php
  include 'navbar.php' 
?>
    <div class="container bg-white mt-3">
        <div class="content row vh-10 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h1 class="text-center">Crear Nueva Sucursal</h1>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <form autocomplete="false">


                    <label class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" for="Nombre">Sucursal:
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Sucursal" id="sucursal"
                            placeholder="Escribe la nueva Sucursal" required>
                        <input class="btn btn-dark btn-md mb-3 mt-3 " style="margin-left: 15px;" type="button"
                            value="Agregar Sucursal" id="Agregar_sucursal">
                    </label>



                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container bg-white mt-3">
        <h2 class="text-center">Sucursales Existentes</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <table style="margin:auto; width:55%; margin-bottom: 5vw;"
                class="table table-hover table-bordered bg-light text-black">
                <thead>
                    <th style="font-size: 23px;">Nombre</th>

                    <th style="margin:auto; width:12%; font-size: 23px;">Acciones</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    const pag = 'crud.php'; //ruta pagina php crud o consulta 

    //al terminar de cargar
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        PintaTabla(); //dibujo la tabla
    });

    // al hacer click en el boton Agregar_sucursal
    Agregar_sucursal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //detengo el envio del form
        FetchAsynAwait(pag, {
            'sucursal': sucursal.value
        }, 'text').then((ret) => { //envio por fetch
            sucursal.value = '';
            if (ret == 'ok') {
                PintaTabla(); //si todo sale bien actualizo la tabla
            } else {
                alert(ret); //algo salio mal
            }
        })
    });

    // fincion para eliminar una sucursal
    const borra = (e) => {
        FetchAsynAwait(pag, {
            'borra': e
        }, 'text').then((ret) => {
            console.log(ret);
        });
    }

    // funcion que me dibuja la tabla
    const PintaTabla = () => {
        FetchAsynAwait(pag, {
            'consulta': true
        }).then((ret) => {
            let tbody = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
                tbody += `
            <tr style="background:white;">
            <td style="font-size: 20px;">${ret[i].NOMBRE_SUCURSAL}</td>
            <td class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <span onclick="borra(${ret[i].ID_SUCURSAL});" role="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></td>
            <tr>
        `;
            }
            document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = tbody;
        });
    }

    // funcion async fetch
    const FetchAsynAwait = async (pag, dataJson, r = 'json') => {
        const opciones = {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            body: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        try {
            const fetchResp = await fetch(pag, opciones);
            const retorna = await r === 'json' ? fetchResp.json() : fetchResp.text();
            return retorna;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Para el archivo que ejecuta el php, yo le llame **crud.php** tu puedes cambiarlo pero recuerda comentarlo en el JavaScript en la **const pag**

```php
<?php
include 'model/conexion.php';

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if (!empty($json['sucursal'])) {
    $nombre = $json['sucursal'];
    $consulta = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO sucursal(NOMBRE_SUCURSAL) 
     VALUES(?);");
    $result = $consulta->execute([$nombre]);
    if ($result == true) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "no se pudo agregar el contacto";
    }
}
if (!empty($json['consulta'])) {
    $consulta = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sucursal;");
    echo json_encode($consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ),true);
}
if (!empty($json['borra'])) {
    echo $json['borra']; // este es el ID_SUCURSAL
   // Aca tu consulta de borrar
}
```

Te escribí el JavaScript comentado para que logres entender como funciona,
espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Disuclpa Jefferson Jimenez pero no funciono, es dificil volver a colocar otra ves el codigo. mil disculpas pero no es la respuesta que busco.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando soluciones encontre en otras perguntas un codigo de redireccion que es este:

```
echo "<script>location.href='sucursal.php'</script>";
```

tambien desactive el cache y funciono, no se si era la version de PHP en el hosting Siteground o que no funciona el Heder pero con esa redireccion logro que se mostrara y me volviera a la pagina principal que era sucursal.php, les doy las muchas gracias a todos por sus consejos y apoyos, disculpen por la pregunta y capas no me supe expresar bien, que tengan un hermoso dia.